# Easiest way to develop simple GUI in Python

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm done with my class project which I coded using Python. I'm working on the extra credit part i.e. GUI development - Windows platform.

I need something simple, easy to use, possibly drag-and-drop GUI development tool for Python. GUI needs to look somewhat like google, since all my project does is:

```
input: Company name
output: Ethical or Unethical
```

So, all I need is:

- An attractive image
- Input textbox
- Search button
- Output box

Comment: The image is not an issue here. If you have one, you can include it in any devent GUI toolkit. If you don't have one, that's not the GUi toolkit's business (and in fact off-topic at SO).

Comment: For future reference, since this appears in Google searches, **[softwarerecs.SE] is the right place for these questions now, and [there is a general version of this question there already](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21253/python-gui-framework)** but you may need more specific help, and that Stack Exchange will be willing to help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take your pick [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

[Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is in the Python stdlib.

Comment: Tkinter is standard in python, but not preinstalled by some distros (Ubuntu, I'm lookin' at you).

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: There was exactly this issue the other day, but I seem to have it pre-installed on Maverick.

Comment: // , Oh wow, a link to a vast list of options, many of which are defunct or unsuitable, with no context? What luck!

Comment: To be fair, this was 8 years ago.

Answer (score 13):

Try with Kivy! [kivy.org](http://kivy.org)
It's quite easy, multi platform and a really good documentation

Comment: I'm not sure in what world kivy is easy.  Maybe compared to PyQt, but it's not easy.

Comment: Lol! Definitely programming is not easy and kivy is a complete framework, so is not that easy.

Comment: /r/HailCorporate

Answer (score 11):

Tkinter is simple but is too ugly. PyQT can do everything you want but is too big. Perhaps IronPython will be good for you. Take a look at this: [Python guis](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

Answer (score 6):

[Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) or [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

[EasyGUI](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html) for very easy GUI Development

Comment: EasyGUI is indeed quite simple. However, it's more like a series of popup alerts rather than a GUI that stays in front of the user. Do you have any other alternatives that don't require me to "generate python code" from the UI? Something similar like EasyGUI except that it can stay on the screen even after the user clicks on a button?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) although it is pretty big. It has all the features that normal QT has, and that's why it's very usable. I think you can use [QML](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-index.html) with it too.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wxpython.
It's very easy to use and the documentation is pretty good.